# What does this syntax mean in React Native and TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native

```
var = ({ data }: { data: interfaceModel }) => (
  // data is used here
)
```

What does this syntax mean? I know that the second `data` has an interface of `interfaceModel`. But why are there two occurrences of `data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that it is a function and its argument must be an object which should contain a key `data` and data should contain keys which are defined in interfaceModal, { data } this is the argument,  { data: interfaceModel } this is the type

example

```
interface interfaceModel {
   name:string
   age:number
}
interface DataModel {
   data: interfaceModel
}

const myFunc = ({ data }: { data: interfaceModel }) => (
  // data is used here
)

let myData:DataModel = {data:{name:'Your name', age:32}}

myFunc(myData);
```

`myFunc` can also be defined like

```
   const myFunc = (myData:dataModel) => (
      // myData.data is used here
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var = ({ data }: { data: interfaceModel }) => (
  // data is used here
)
```

First `{ data }` is a destructured property. You can write the same function in this way:

```js
var = (props: { data: interfaceModel }) => (
  props.data // valid
)
```

Second `{data: interfaceModel}` is just a literal representation of type.

You can rewrite it in this way:

```js
interface Data {
 data: interfaceModel
}

var = (props: Data) => (
  props.data // valid
)
```